# Active Directory Authentication from the Internet

Tags: active-directory, mac-osx, internet

I need some help finding a good solution to this problem. I know AD just fine, but admittedly, I'm not an expert. And I know I don't want to expose it to the internet...

I inherited a workforce at my new company (~100 employees, all Mac) that often work remote. Every laptop authenticates to the Active Directory. Works great(ish). 
However, when users go remote, they sometimes need to leave their laptop with another employee that doesn't have a laptop (for reasons). The problem is that employee 2 can't login to employee 1's laptop because the computer cannot contact the AD. There are no cached creds for employee 2 because its the first time he's logged in to this particular machine.

Normally VPN is the solution, but without being able to login to the computer first, you can't login to the VPN. Are there any solutions that I should look into not involving persistent VPN to help with this? I don't want to expose AD or LDAP to the wider internet, but the bottom line is that I need to be able to authenticate from there without VPN.

Also, just to add a layer of complexity on top of this...the domain I inherited is a "domain.local" Not too big of an issue (I can work around some of the normal mac problems), however I see this causing an issue when trying to contact dc.domain.local from the internet.

Can anyone smarter than me point me in the right direction for a solution (without a lecture on bad practice, etc)?

Answer (score 0):

Im posting as an answer due to lack of reputations, but its more of a thinking-out-loud response. Apple Configurator and Profile Manager has a ***"Always-On VPN"*** options. However, it only works on "Supervised" devices. I dont know whether laptops can be supervised. Also you need a VPN server that supports IKE**v2**

[image: Profile Manager]

Comment: The OP did mention `Are there any solutions that I should look into not involving persistent VPN to help with this?`. There are plenty of persistent VPN solutions out there, but he specifically does not want one.